# How to make new text lines in div stay on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stumped of how to make a new line appear on top of the div element, i.e. whenever the button is clicked, the new textline is on top and the previous goes below. Right now, the new textline is underneath the first one when I press another button and not above. So my question is: How do you make the new text lines stay on top and not underneath?

JavaScript:

```
var LineText=""

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $('.stashText').html(LineText+="<br><br>Line_No_1");
}); 
});



$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn2Submit").click(function(){
        $('.stashText').html(LineText+="<br><br>Line_No_2");
}); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type=button id="btnSubmit">S
</button>
<button type=button id="btn2Submit">S2
</button>

<br>
<br>
<div class="stashText">

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AllanNyk/r09dsp1d/13/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use jquerys "prepend" function, look here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $('.stashText').prepend("<br><br>Line_No_1");
}); 
});



$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn2Submit").click(function(){
        $('.stashText').prepend("<br><br>Line_No_2");
}); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r09dsp1d/14/

Comment: Maybe use `$(function () { /* CODE */ });` Instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepend` instead.

```
 var LineText=""

 $(document).ready(function() { $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
         $('.stashText').prepend("<br><br>Line_No_1"); });  });



 $(document).ready(function() { $("#btn2Submit").click(function(){
         $('.stashText').prepend("<br><br>Line_No_2"); });  });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r09dsp1d/15/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.prepend` instead of `.html`
Here is your updated jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qcma197k/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        $('.stashText').prepend("<br><br>Line_No_1");
    }); 

    $("#btn2Submit").click(function() {
        $('.stashText').prepend("<br><br>Line_No_2");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `LineText+="<br><br>Line_No_1"` to `"<br><br>Line_No_1" + LineText`:

```js
var LineText = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    LineText = "<br><br>Line_No_1" + LineText;
    $('.stashText').html(LineText);
  });
  $("#btn2Submit").click(function() {
    LineText = "<br><br>Line_No_2" + LineText;
    $('.stashText').html(LineText);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type=button id="btnSubmit">S</button>
<button type=button id="btn2Submit">S2</button>

<br>
<br>
<div class="stashText"></div>
```

Also, there's no need to call `$(document).ready()` twice.